# Add HTML to a specific cell in DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataGrid that is populated using a DataTable.

The last row of the DataTable is a sum of the column.  I'd like to add HTML code (HTML code will call javascript, which will show a tooltip) to a specific column, of the last row.

So I'd like to do something like this

```
DataTable dtName = new DataTable();
//**code that populates dtName**
dtName.Rows[dtName.Rows.Count - 1]["Column4_sum"] = "<a onclick=ShowToolTip('ToolTip','This is a sum');>" + dtName.Rows[dtName.Rows.Count - 1]["Column4_sum"] + "</a>";

dataGrid.DataSource = dtName;
dataGrid.DataBind();
```

I'm getting an error of

> Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <61920> in
>   Column4_sum Column.  Expected type is Decimal.

I understand that I can't store a string in a decimal.  I'm looking for any type of solution.  Like modifying the DataGrid after it's binded?  Or maybe some type of column property that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it, you are changing the value in the DataTable.
You can try to to populate the grid using a for loop instead of DataBind, dataGrid.Rows.Add() and utilize at a cell level the following

> .Attributes.Add("onclick", "Your javascript");

Comment: He is talking about `DataGrid` and as you know it contains multiple row.

Comment: he can add the rows and then at the end can the above snipnet

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to resolve my issue.

```
protected void dataGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e){

if (**code to identify last row in DataGrid. Our data had a flag to identify which is the last row**)
  e.Item.Cells[4].Text = "<a onclick=ShowToolTip('ToolTip','This&#32;is&#32;a&#32;sum');>" + e.Item.Cells[4].Text + "</a>";
}
```

I had to use `&#32;` instead of just using a space for some reason or else it'll replace a space with "".  Not sure why.

I'm not too fond of the hard coded Cells[4].  But there's no overloaded method for it that'll accept a string, so this will suffice for now.